# How to use programmatically created schedule object in resource pool in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to programmatically create a schedule from inputs and use it as capacity for my `resourcePoolSortation`. However, I cannot assign this new schedule as "Capacity defined by On/Off schedule" for my resource pool. AnyLogic wants the schedule to be an object dragged and dropped into Canvas. What is the way out of this situation?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

what you did is correct with one difference,

make a parameter with name schedule of type Schedule
default value of this parameter is a function called `getSchedule()`

and in this function you write the code

```
long [] starts= {3,6};
long [] ends ={5,9};
Object [] values={true,false};
Schedule schedule=new Schedule<Boolean>(
    this, false, SUNDAY, 24L*TIME_UNIT_HOUR, TIME_UNIT_HOUR, 
    null, false,starts,ends,values, false, null, true );
return schedule;
```

finally, the resourcepool will have the parameter as the schedule selected

Comment: Thank you Felipe. This helps. The issue is; `start` and `end` of the shift are parameters of the Warehouse agent. All these parameters are read from an input file. It seems AnyLogic executes the schedule when I do `add_warehouses()` and at that point the  `start` and `end` are null. There is no way of updating the resourcePool schedule in the course of the simulation?

Comment: not possible, that's why I never use schedules, instead i have my own Agent-Based framework. It makes things way more flexible

Comment: actually it is possible if you follow my example... since the parameter is initialized before anything else... you just need to understand what is the order in which things are created